# Add discord role to someone in direct message

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot where you can activate your key with `!activate`.
At the event i want the bot to give the `message.author` the `PREMIUM MEMBER` role at my discord.
How can i make that work

I'm using @client.event and not ctx.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the guild object that the bot is in, so then it knows where to get the role from. Additionally, the `message.author` object will return a User, not a Member,  but we'll need the Member object in order to add a role.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!activate") and not message.guild:
        guild = client.get_guild(112233445566778899) # the guild's ID
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="PREMIUM MEMBER") # or you can use id=
        member = await guild.fetch_member(message.author.id)
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.fetch_member()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_member)
- [`Client.get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)

Comment: No worries! Good luck with the bot :^)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
def check_activation_key(activation_key):
    # do your check here, return True or False

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith('!activate ') and message.channel == message.author.dm_channel: # !activate, dms only
        activation_key = message.content[10:]
        if check_activation_key(activation_key):
            guild = client.get_guild(ID_OF_SERVER_TO_ASSIGN_ROLE_IN) # right click and "copy id"
            role = guild.get_role(ID_OF_ROLE_TO_ASSIGN) # right click and "copy id"
            await guild.get_member(message.author.id).add_roles(role)
    if message.content.startswith('!unactivate') and message.channel == message.author.dm_channel:
        guild = client.get_guild(ID_OF_SERVER_TO_TAKE_ROLE_IN)
        if ('PREMIUM MEMBER' in [role.name for role in guild.get_member(message.author.id).roles]):
            await guild.get_member(message.author.id).remove_roles(guild.get_role(ID_OF_ROLE_GOES_HERE))
        else:
            await message.channel.send('You did not verify yet')
```

A drawback is that this does not support multiple servers, only 1, but you can make different activator commands with different server IDs.

Get the ID of a guild by right clicking the icon/banner and choosing "copy id". Get the ID of a role by right clicking a role (either in server settings or in someones profile) and choosing "copy id".

Comment: i did not test your answer but i made it work now. Thank you anyways for your answer